# Despgraph update handler is never called?

Tags: python, depsgraph

I'm registering a depsgraph update handler but it is never called. Am I doing something wrong? What causes the handler to trigger?

```
def depsgraph_callback(scene, depsgraph):
  print('Do something')

def register():
  bpy.app.handlers.depsgraph_update_post.append(depsgraph_callback)
```

**Edit:**

The above code is only a snippet. I realize I didn't make that clear.

I think the issue is that I have the addon files located in the blender install directory, so that I don't have to re-zip every time I make a change. For some reason only the app handler isn't registering because of this, everything else like props seems to register fine. I have to manually disable and enable the addon for the handler to register. This doesn't happen when I zip the addon and install like normal, or if I register the handler using the blender text editor.

Anyone know what's going on here? Is this a bug? It's kind of a pain to have to re-enable the addon every time I make a change. Usually I will just restart blender and it will register as expected.

Comment: Does the handler get called ever or not?  The first part of your question says "never" but the edit implies "after a re-register."  In the second case, my answer below explains your issue; as does the manual page I pointed to.

Comment: @hilift please do not vandalize your posts. If it is no longer useful to you it may still be valuable for someone else in the same situation.

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> def depsgraph_callback(scene, depsgraph):
...   print('Do something')
... 
>>> def register():
...   bpy.app.handlers.depsgraph_update_post.append(depsgraph_callback)
...   
>>> register()
>>>
```

works just fine and produces

```
Read prefs: C:\Users\stupi\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.93\config\userpref.blend
HardOps 0.9.87.29 available!
Do something
Do something
Do something
Do something
Do something
```

on my console window; but only after I've called the register routine.

Your problem seems to be that you haven't actually called `register()`.

Also, if you wish the function to run whenever a new Blender instance is invoked, you need the `@persistent` decorator.  That said, here's a complete working example, with a correct function definition:

```py
import bpy
from bpy.app.handlers import persistent

@persistent
def depsgraph_callback(scene, depsgraph):
  print('Do something')

def register():
  bpy.app.handlers.depsgraph_update_post.append(depsgraph_callback)
  
register()
```

as described in the [Application Handlers example.](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.app.handlers.html)

Comment: Footnote: app handlers use "magic" Python/C interfaces in [blender/bpy_app_handlers.c](https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/594f47ecd2d5367ca936cf6fc6ec8168c2b360d0/source/blender/python/intern/bpy_app_handlers.c) and although I can find no use for it, the callback has a variable length argument list [implementation](https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/594f47ecd2d5367ca936cf6fc6ec8168c2b360d0/source/blender/python/intern/bpy_app_handlers.c#L314).